# How do i set up Apache Kafka's Replication Factor?

Tags: apache-kafka

I was just wondering how can i set replication factor in apache kafka? I can't find a good tutorial out there about this, I'm learning this for a mini project.

If you have any links, Please link it down

Comment: A good starting point to learn about replication factors and how to set them is the Apache Kafka documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the broker properties, you define both internal and default auto-created topic replication factors. Ideally, you'd disable auto creation, however

Any other topic creation API requires replication factor to be specified, so refer any documentation you can find, starting with the official Kafka website